# Purifying company shares where the company contributes?

Tags: halal-haram, finance

The company I work for provides me with shares in its parent company, where I have a minimum amount I have to 'purchase' every year before income tax and then the company I work for also contribute on top of that.

I can only sell them after 5 years of having purchased them. I've worked there for ~10 years, so I have 5 years worth of stocks I can sell.

Let's say I bought two lots of shares a year, and the company bought one lot on my behalf. Now the 5 years worth of shares (3×5) are worth £150.

When I look up the parent companies shares on a stock screening website the parent company is listed as Haram, so I know I need to either donate all of my available stocks or somehow purify them?

I've done a little research, and I'm sure I've read that you need to take into account the amount you bought the stocks for when purifying. But not only do I not know what the stocks were worth 10 years ago I don't know how to account for my company's contribution.

How do I go about purifying these shares (if I don't need to just donate all of it away)?